# What is the sum of the binomial coefficients ${n\choose p}$ over prime numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients

What is known about the asymptotic order and/or lower and upper bound of the sum of the binomial coefficients

$$
S_n = {n\choose 2} + {n\choose 3} + {n\choose 5} + \cdots + {n\choose p}
$$

where the sum runs over all primes $\le n$?

**Update 12-Aug-2019**: Sungjin Kim has shown that almost for all $n$,

$$
S_n \sim \frac{2^n}{\log(n/2)}
$$
In the previous version we had $\log n$ in the denominator which has not been corrected.

**Actual values:** My calculation gave the following asymptotic order of $n$ and the ratio $r_n = s_n/(2^n/\log n)$.

```
(100000, 1.13766407097665)
(110000, 1.00289966767667)
(120000, 0.97497422941139)
(130000, 1.07297773163979)
(140000, 1.09130325488627)
(150000, 1.03493135205282)
(160000, 1.09228831426585)
(170000, 1.02437859352022)
(180000, 1.18789309596329)
(190000, 1.11814470079054)
(200000, 1.00572021128112)
(210000, 1.03114155491856)
(220000, 0.95835641265769)
(230000, 1.03176200981585)
(240000, 1.10141025102049)
(250000, 1.04435554152951)
(260000, 1.02244981941248)
(270000, 1.03103959797895)
(280000, 1.05303304022584)
(290000, 1.00915670279005)
(300000, 1.08798558856723)
(310000, 1.05106334090960)
(320000, 1.07582903038813)
(330000, 0.920056638088384)
(340000, 1.13576974339066)
(350000, 0.923576122540866)
(360000, 1.15321376273496)
(370000, 1.08344303929811)
(380000, 1.02063510069254)
(390000, 1.08363394859595)
(400000, 1.05463839543006)
(410000, 1.04986600633135)
```

Comment: Here it is in oeis: https://oeis.org/A121497

Comment: The asymptotics should be dominated by the distribution of primes near $\frac{n}{2}$. By the PNT we expect such primes to locally have a density of about $\frac{1}{\log \frac{n}{2}}$. So a rough guess for the asymptotics is $O \left( \frac{1}{\log n} {n \choose n/2} \right)$, which works out to something like $O \left( \frac{2^n}{\sqrt{n} \log n} \right)$. This shouldn't be hard to get experimental data on.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan According to your guess, $O(\frac{2^n}{\log n})$ is plausible since you began with the density.

Comment: I think we may be able to prove something like $\frac {2^n}{\log n} \ll S_n \ll \frac{2^n \log\log n}{\log n}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan. I think this approach will work. The square root in the denominator looks a little doubtful.

Comment: Experimentally $O(2^n/(\log n))$ looks more likely than the form with the square root.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this up again. It gave me one more chance to think about the problem. It may be possible to prove $S_n \sim \frac{2^n}{\log n}$. It will be great if you can add more values of $n$ and include a link to those.

Comment: That will be interesting... Alright i will redo the calculation for higher values of n

Comment: I saw your cross-posting on MO. It looks like there is no currently known asymptotics. Now I think that it is possible to prove the asymptotic, maybe it is worth trying submitting for a publication. Here's my email address, 707107@gmail.com. It will be good to include the data you obtained. Also, @QiaochuYuan, please let me know if you are interested in making this posting as a publication, since you are the main idea provider.

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking of the same. How about a joint paper. If not anything else, you will get Erdos No 3 (assuming you aren't) lol ... I have arrived at the same results yours using a different but longer approach so yours is more elegant.

Comment: Yes, a joint paper sounds good. To do this, I think e-mail is a better for our communication. Just out of curiosity, may I ask about your publication which you obtained Erdos number 2?

Comment: Goldbach conjecture suggest for even n there's at least one pair of coefficients equal.

Comment: Why does a definitive expression for $S_n$ not exist? even if it is in terms of $\pi(n)$?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor We may be able to prove something like $s_n \sim \frac{2^n}{n} \pi(n)$.

Comment: Maybe current knowledge is not enough for solving $s_n\sim \frac{2^n}n\pi(n)$. I tried using the zero density estimate of Huxley. But, I was not successful in resolving an error in my argument. I still think that it is possible something like $s_n\sim \frac{2^n}n \pi(n)$ for almost all $n$. This is a considerably weaker statement.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor There can be multiple reason for $S_n$ not having definitive expression. The most prominent reason is the huge fluctuation of binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Following Qiaochu Yuan's approach, the inequalities 
$$
\frac{2^n}{\log n} \ll S_n \ll \frac{2^n }{\log n}
$$
seems plausible. The lower bound is a conjecture, but it is possible to prove the upper bound.

**Notations in this answer**

$T_n \sim \mathrm{B}(n,\frac12)$ is the binomial distribution.

$S_n=\sum_{p\leq n} \binom np$ summed over  $p$ prime.

$\pi(y)=\sum_{p\leq y}1$ is the prime counting function.

$A(n)\ll B(n)$ means $|A(n)|\leq CB(n)$ for some absolute constant $C>0$.

**Lower Bound (Conjecture)**

Fix $x>0$. We have
$$
P\left(p \mathrm {\ is \ prime}, \  T_n=p, \ \frac n2 -x\sqrt n\leq T_n \leq \frac n2 + x\sqrt n\right) \leq \frac {S_n}{2^n}.
$$
Since binomial coefficients $\binom nk$ peak at $k=n/2$ and become smaller when $k$ is further away from $n/2$, we take the following as a lower bound of the probability.

$$
\left(\pi(\frac n2+x\sqrt n)-\pi(\frac n2-x\sqrt n)\right)P\left(T_n=\lfloor \frac n2+x\sqrt n\rfloor\right).
$$

By Stirling's formula, and $\log (1+t)=t-\frac{t^2}2+O(\frac1{t^3})$ for $|t|\leq 1/2$, we have
$$
P\left(T_n=\lfloor \frac n2+x\sqrt n\rfloor\right)\sim \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi n}} e^{-2x^2}.
$$

If we have the following conjecture (see [this survey by Yildrim](http://www.math.boun.edu.tr/instructors/yildirim/paper/paper9.pdf) for more information), 
$$
\pi(\frac n2+x\sqrt n)-\pi(\frac n2-x\sqrt n)\sim \frac{2x\sqrt n}{\log n},
$$
then we have the conjectural lower bound
$$
\frac{4x\cdot 2^n}{e^{2x^2}\sqrt{2\pi}\log n} \lesssim S_n.
$$

**Upper Bound (Easy Version)**

By [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality), we give a bound of sum over primes further away from $n/2$. 
$$
P\left(p \mathrm {\ is \ prime}, \  T_n=p, \ |T_n-\frac n2|>\sqrt{n \log\log n} \right) 
$$
$$
\leq P\left( |T_n-\frac n2|\geq \sqrt{n \log\log n}\right)\leq 2e^{-2\log\log n}\ll \frac{1}{(\log n)^2}.
$$
For the primes close to $n/2$, we apply Brun-Titchmarsh inequality, 
$$
P\left(p \mathrm {\ is \ prime}, \  T_n=p, \ |T_n-\frac n2|\leq \sqrt {n \log\log n }\right) $$
$$\leq \left(\pi(\frac n2 + \sqrt {n \log\log n})-\pi(\frac n2-\sqrt {n \log\log n})\right)P\left(T_n=\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor\right)
$$
$$
\ll \frac{\sqrt{n\log\log n}}{\log n} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt n} = \frac{\sqrt{\log\log n}}{\log n}.
$$
Therefore, we have the upper bound 
$$
S_n\ll \frac{2^n\sqrt{\log\log n}}{\log n}.
$$

**Upper Bound (Added on 9/28)**

With more care, we can remove $\sqrt{\log\log n}$ from the upper bound.

Again, by Hoeffding's inequality, 
$$
P\left(p \mathrm {\ is \ prime}, \  T_n=p, \ |T_n-\frac n2|>\sqrt{n \log\log n} \right) \ll \frac1{(\log n)^2}.
$$

For the primes in $|T_n-\frac n2|\leq\sqrt{n \log\log n} $, consider the subintervals
$$
\frac n2 + x\sqrt n \leq p < \frac n2 + (x+1)\sqrt n
$$
for nonnegative integers $x\leq \sqrt{\log\log n}$ first.

Then the negative integers $-\sqrt{\log\log n}\leq x$ are treated similarly.

The number of primes in this interval is by Brun-Titchmarsh inequality, $\ll \frac{\sqrt n}{\log n}$, while 
$$P(T_n=p)\leq P\left(T_n=\lfloor \frac n2 + x\sqrt n\rfloor\right)\sim \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi n}} e^{-2x^2}.$$

Note that the last asymptotic still holds if $|x|\leq \sqrt{\log\log n}$. Then we have

$$
P\left(p \mathrm {\ is \ prime}, \ T_n=p, \ \frac n2 + x\sqrt n \leq p < \frac n2 + (x+1)\sqrt n\right)
$$
$$
\ll \frac{\sqrt n}{\log n} \cdot \frac{e^{-2x^2}}{\sqrt n}.
$$
Thus by summing over $x$, 
$$
P\left(p \mathrm {\ is \ prime}, \  T_n=p, \ |T_n-\frac n2|\leq \sqrt {n \log\log n }\right)$$
$$\ll \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2x^2}}{\log n}\ll \frac 1{\log n}.
$$
Therefore, we obtain
$$
S_n\ll \frac{2^n}{\log n}.
$$

**Update on 2019/3/4**

Nilotpal Kanti Sinha and I started working on writing a paper on this subject. Here is current progress. The proofs are too long to be contained here, but the main idea of splitting up the sum into short intervals is  present in this answer. To prove 1, we need Huxley's zero density estimate and its consequence on the primes in the short intervals. (Chapter 5 of this note by Angel Kumchev:  https://tigerweb.towson.edu/akumchev/a5.pdf).

1. We have for almost all $n$,
   $$
   S_n= \frac{2^n}{\log n}+O\left(\frac{2^n}{(\log n)^2}\right) \ \textrm{as }n\rightarrow \infty.
   $$

Here, almost all means that the number of $n\in [1,N]\cap \mathbb{Z}$ for which the asymptotic formula fails is $o(N)$.

2. We have
   $$
   \alpha:=\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{S_n\log n}{2^n}\leq 1\leq \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{S_n \log n}{2^n} \leq 4.
   $$
3. The statement $\alpha>0$ implies that, there is $b>0$ and $N_0(b)>0$ such that,
   $$
   \pi\left(\frac n2 +\sqrt {n\log\log n}\right)-\pi\left( \frac n2-\sqrt {n\log\log n}\right)\geq \frac{b\sqrt n}{\log n} \ \textrm{for all }n\geq N_0(b).
   $$

Comment: This looks very impressive and non-trivial. Let me take some time to go through it in details. By the way, whats with the number 707107?

Comment: This is very interesting problem. The number is by the way, came from $1/\sqrt 2$.

Comment: I just came up with a little stronger upper bound. I will edit.

Comment: I wonder under what assumptions if any can the square root term in the upper bound be replaced by $1+\epsilon$

Comment: Note that I used trivial bound $\binom nk \leq \binom n {n/2}$. If we are more careful on $|T_n-\frac n2|\leq \sqrt{n\log\log n}$, we might be able to remove that $\sqrt{\log\log n}$ in the upper bound.

Comment: Are you using $\ll$ to mean much less than? Because after your latest edit, the upper and lower bound are the same.

Comment: I put the meaning of $\ll$ on top. This notation is Vinogradov's notation. $\ll$ means the same of the big-Oh.