# Where does $\pi^2$ appear spontaneously within Physical Phenomenon and Mathematics Equations?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, big-list, pi

The term $\pi$ is found to appear in many equations and natural phenomenon; however my question is related to $\pi^2$.

While trying to figure out the reason for some $\pi^2$ terms appearing in certain equalities that I came across, I have a question. And the question is this:

> In which all mathematics/physics equation or contexts does $\pi^2$ appear inherently?

-- and (now this second part is merely a follow up question that did not form part of the original query but added later)  where that $\pi^2$ term can lend some interpretation of the underlying phenomenon, just like does $\pi$ whereby we can interpret (in most cases i.e.) that some type of circular ambulation in 1 dimension is involved??

As you can understand, the $\pi^2$ term is more complex and does not directly lend itself to an interpretation -- as opposed to $\pi$ which is very intuitive.

Thanks

Comment: volume of a $4$-ball?

Comment: [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem)

Comment: The volume of a torus.

Comment: @Kumar The question is still ambiguous unless you define what you mean by naturally as it may be interpreted as the physical/natural world. I suggest you re-title   it to something like - Where does $\pi^2$ appear in mathematics or physics?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, Kumar, by "spontaneously", or by "inherently". Also, $\pi$ appears in a great many places with nothing to do with circles.

Answer (score 37):

$$
g \approx \pi^2\,\mathrm{m/s^2}
$$

The reason for this the original definition of the meter: the length of a pendulum whose half-period is 1 second. Much like the original definition of the Celsius scale, this allowed a person to easily calibrate equipment with common materials. (Of course, this calibration is hardly precise enough for modern measurements, so the meter has been redefined more than once to keep up with the times.) The $\pi^2$ then comes from the small-angle approximation to the period of a pendulum:
$$
T = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}\;\; \Longrightarrow\;\; g = \pi^2 \frac{L}{(T/2)^2}
$$

Comment: Interesting.  The value of gravitational acceleration we use today implies the meter has grown by a few tenths of a percent.

Comment: I thought the meter was originally chosen to be a convenient fraction of the distance from the equator to the north pole (but using an inaccurate geoid).

Answer (score 30):

A great example in my opinion is the [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem)
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}
= \frac{\pi^2}{6}.
$$
A great intuitive and geometric explanation can be found in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-o3eB9sfls&frags=pl%2Cwn), which, along with the whole channel, I cannot recommend enough.

There's also a whole [Stack Exchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189023/geometric-interpretation-of-the-basel-problem/2714400#2714400) dedicated to it.

Answer (score 15):

You can get arbitrarily-high powers of $\pi$ (though divided by factorials) using [involutes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involute):

[image]

- A semicircle of radius $1$ has length $\pi$.
- The involute of the semicircle has length $\tfrac12\pi^2$
- The involute of that involute (emerging from the same point) has length $\tfrac1{6}\pi^3$.
- The involute of *that* involute (emerging from the same point) has length $\tfrac1{24}\pi^4$.
- The involute of *that* involute (emerging from the same point) has length $\tfrac1{120}\pi^5$.
- ... and so forth ...

---

**Note:** The polygonal spiral formed by joining the involutes' non-common endpoints has edge-lengths equal to those powers of $\pi$. (The right-most vertical edge has length $\pi$, the top-most horizontal edge has length $\tfrac12\pi^2$, etc.) Throw in a segment from the semicircle's right endpoint to its center, and you have an edge of length $1 = \tfrac{1}{1}\pi^0$.

**Note:** That polygonal spiral converges on the involutes' common endpoint. The back-and-forth-ing of the horizontal edges implies that
$$\tfrac11\pi^0 - \tfrac12\pi^2 + \tfrac1{24}\pi^4 - \cdots \;=\; -1$$
Likewise, the up-and-down-ing of the vertical edges implies
$$\tfrac11\pi^1 - \tfrac16\pi^3 + \tfrac1{120}\pi^5 - \cdots \;=\; 0$$
Of course, these values are, respectively, $\cos\pi$ and $\sin\pi$. The above is a special case of [Chaikovsky's Involute Pinwheel](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2758743/409) for the power series of cosine and sine.

Answer (score 13):

If you're looking for examples of $\pi^2$ occurring naturally, you should look at some of the common PDEs. The derivation of their solutions and solutions themselves lead to occurrences of $\pi^2$. I'll provide some examples, but I'm going to keep everything a bit loose to make it more digestible.

First, take the heat equation on a 1-D rod of length $L$ with no heat on the ends: $$\begin{cases} 
\partial_t u=\kappa\partial_x^2 u\\ 
u(x,0)=f(x)\\ 
u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0
\end{cases}$$ If you assume a solution of the form $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t),$ then you will arrive at two ODEs to solve: $$\frac{d^2X}{dx^2}=-\lambda X$$ and $$\frac{dT}{dt}=-\kappa\lambda T,$$ with $X(0)=0$ and $X(L)=0$. The former is an eigenvalue problem with given boundary data, and solving this eigenvalue problem gives you $\pi^2$ presence, as we find the eigenvalues to be $$\lambda_n=\left(\frac{n\pi }{L}\right)^2,$$ and $$X_n(x)=\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right),$$ for $n=1,2,\cdots.$ Solving the $T$ equation gives you $$T(t)=ce^{-\kappa\lambda_n t},$$ and in the end, you get the solution $$u(x,t)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty B_n\sin \left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) e^{-\kappa\frac{n^2\pi^2}{L^2} t},$$ with $$B_n=\frac{2}{L}\int\limits_0^L f(x)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\, dx.$$ This even has $\pi^2$ in the solution itself. Notice that, amongst other things, $\pi^2$ pops up in the decay rate of the solution to its steady state.

If we look at the wave equation $$\partial_t^2u=c^2\partial_x^2 u,$$ instead, then you will still get the same eigenvalues and eigenfunctions (since they are all eigenvalues/eigenfunctions of $\partial_x^2$). If we add in the additional initial condition $\partial_t u(x,0)=g(x),$ then we instead get the final solution $$u(x,t)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(A_n\cos\left(\frac{n\pi ct}{L}\right)+B_n\sin \left(\frac{n\pi ct}{L}\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right), $$ where $A_n$ is the same and $$B_n=\frac{2}{n\pi c}\int\limits_0^Lg(x)\sin \left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\, dx.$$ Here, the eigenvalues are related to the frequencies of the waves, so they have a nice physical interpretation.

Comment: Second one also, needs exponentials.

Comment: @SungjinKim Performing separation of variables, you get ODEs $X''+\lambda X=0$ and $T''+\lambda c^2 T=0.$ I wrote the solution to time ODE using $\sin$ and $\cos$ instead of complex exponentials. It's a pretty standard representation of the solution.

Comment: I see . Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 13):

(1) Let $\mu$ denote the Mobius function:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^{2}} = \frac{6}{\pi^{2}}$$

(2) Let $\sigma(n)$ denote the sum of the divisors of $n$:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sigma(i)}{n^{2}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sigma(1) + \sigma(2) + \ldots + \sigma(n)}{n^{2}} = \frac{\pi^{2}}{12} $$

(3) Let $\phi$ denote Euler's $\phi$-function.

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\phi(i)}{n^{2}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\phi(1) + \phi(2) + \ldots + \phi(n)}{n^{2}} = \frac{3}{\pi^{2}} $$

Comment: OP asked about examples where $\pi^2$ occurred naturally. Your examples are not applicable unless you tell where they occur in nature.

Comment: "In which all mathematics/physics equation or contexts does π^{2} appear *naturally*?"

Comment: By that statement statement OP meant which all equations in the mathematical formulas or derivations of known physics do we use $\pi^2$. I guess what you interpreted is - which all statements in mathematics or in physics do we  use $\pi^2$. These are two different questions. For example, there are parametric equations which the value of $\pi^2$ for infinite inputs. So if all you wanted was $\pi^2$, we can get infinitely many such equations or formulas. So the  physical context of mathematics in important here. Just see why other answers are focusing on physical use of $\pi^2$

Comment: @Nil, what makes you so sure you know what OP meant?

Comment: @GerryMyerson OP said "The term π is found to appear in many equations and natural phenomenon". OP also said "In which all mathematics/physics equation or contexts does $\pi^2$ appear naturally?" The keywords for me here are "natural phenomenon" and "naturally"

Comment: @Nil, the keywords for me are "many equations" and "mathematics". Unless OP chooses to clarify, you have no better idea of what was intended than I do, so you may as well enjoy all the nice answers that have been posted.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Let be more picky: One natural phenomenon, one naturally and one physics makes it 3 key words vs one mathematics. Equations belong to both math and physics so not adding it to either. That's 3:1 hehe :)

Answer (score 10):

Usually $(2 \pi)^{-n}$ appears in the $n$ dimensional Fourier transform: If the Fourier transform of a $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is defined as
$$\hat{f}(k)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-i k \cdot x} f(x) \,\mathrm{d}^n x$$
Then the inverse transform will be (if the integral is convergent)
$$f(x)= \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{i k \cdot x} \hat{f}(k) \,\mathrm{d}^n k$$
But you can also "spread" it to be more symmetric: if
$$\hat{f}(k)= \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-i k \cdot x} f(x) \,\mathrm{d}^n x$$
then
$$f(x)= \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{i k \cdot x} \hat{f}(k) \,\mathrm{d}^n k$$

Answer (score 10):

Also related to the Basel problem: the [probability that two random integers are coprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Coprime_integers#Probability_of_coprimality) is $$\frac{6}{\pi^2}$$

(in the sense that the probability that $a,b$ chosen uniformly from $\{1, 2, \ldots, N\}$ are coprime approaches $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$.)

Answer (score 10):

**Euler's solution of Basel problem**: 
Many of the answers posted here talk about Euler's solution of the Basel problem. But an important thing that is notably missing is that Euler's original solution to the Basel problem already had $\pi^2$ in it. Euler used the well know trigonometric identity

$$
\frac{\sin x}{x} = \prod_{n \ge 1} \bigg(1 - \frac{x^2}{\pi^2 n^2}\bigg)
$$

**Ramanujan's first letter to Hardy:**
This one is a part of mathematical folklore, appearing Ramanujan's first letter to Hardy and one of few that Hardy saild he could prove himself out of the many formulas in the letter. If $\alpha \beta = \pi^2$ then

$$
\alpha^{-1/4}\bigg(1 + 4\alpha\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{xe^{-\alpha x^2}}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx\bigg)
= \beta^{-1/4}\bigg(1 + 4\beta\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{xe^{-\beta x^2}}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx\bigg)
$$

**Number of square free integers:**
The number of square free integers $\le x$ is 
$$\dfrac{6x}{\pi^2} + O(\sqrt{x})$$

**Probability of coprime numbers:**
The probability that $n$ positive integers chosen uniformly from $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ have no common factors approaches

$$
\frac{1}{\zeta(2n)} = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2\pi)^{2n}B_{2n}}{2(2n)!}
$$
as $n \rightarrow \infty$, where $B_k$ is the $k$-th Bernoulli number.

**Others:**
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{F_{2n}}{ n^2 {2n \choose n}} = \frac{4\pi^2}{25\sqrt 5}, \text{where $F_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number}
$$

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{r = 1}^n n(\textrm{mod } r) = 1 - \frac{\pi^2}{12}
$$

$$
\int_{0}^{1} \bigg(\frac{\tan^{-1}x}{x}\bigg)^2 dx = G - \frac{\pi^2}{16} + \frac{\pi \log 2}{4}, \text{ where $G$ is the Calatan constant}
$$

Answer (score 9):

List of Places where π^2 can be seen-

1. π is present in some structural engineering formulae, such as the buckling formula derived by Euler, which gives the maximum axial load F that a long, slender column of length L, modulus of elasticity E, and area moment of inertia I can carry without buckling
2. The fact that π is approximately equal to 3 plays a role in the relatively long lifetime of orthopositronium. The inverse lifetime to lowest order in the fine-structure constant α has a term of π^2
3. Kepler's Third Law of Planetary Motion
4. Volume and Bounding Area of 4-D and 5-D Sphere
5. Basel Problem (As mentioned in another answer)

   And many more as well

Sources-

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckling

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler's_laws_of_planetary_motion

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere

Answer (score 8):

The volume of a torus which consists of a tube with radius $r$ centered at a circle with radius $R$ is $4\pi^2Rr$.

Answer (score 7):

How about an even higher power of $\pi$ in the [Stefan-Boltzmann Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law) relating radiant energy flux from a black body to temperature?  This relation involves the *fifth* power of $\pi$:

$\text{Radiant flux}=((2\color{blue}{\pi^5}k^4)/(15c^2h^3))T^4$

The parameters $k, c, h$ are respectively Boltzmann's constant, the speed of light and Planck's constant from physics.  $T$ is absolute temperature.

Answer (score 7):

The number of [three-term geometric progressions](https://www.austms.org.au/Publ/Gazette/2008/Jul08/TechPaperMyerson.pdf) of positive integers with no term exceeding $n$ is $${6\over\pi^2}n\log n+O(n)$$.

Answer (score 6):

The $\text{Riemann Zeta function} \ \  \zeta(s)=\large \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}$ is used in many branch of Science and mathematics. Replacing $s=2$, we have $ \zeta(2)=\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$. In $1735$ Leonard Euler showed that $$ \zeta(2)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{{\color{blue}{\pi^2}}}{6}.$$

This result leads to Number Theory and probability result as follows:

The $ \ {\color{blue}{ probability}} \ $ of two random number being $ \ {\color{blue}{ relatively \ \ prime}} \ $ is given by the following product over all primes
$$ \prod_{p}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{p^2} \right)=\left(\prod_{p}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-p^{-2}} \right)^{-1}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\cdots}=\frac{1}{\zeta(2)}=\frac{6}{{\color{blue}{\pi^2}}} \approx 61 \%.$$

This is an interesting result where $\pi^2$ is involved.

Comment: Both of these results are already mentioned in other answers, right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, who mentioned the last and in fact main part of  my answer? I portrayed here that $\pi^2$ is used to mention the probability of two random number being relatively prime. I don't see anyone used in this question

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298039/where-does-pi2-appear-spontaneously-within-physical-phenomenon-and-mathemati/3298242#3298242

Comment: @GerryMyerson, both answers have big difference in presentation, ok

Answer (score 5):

Here is perhaps the newest result on $\pi^2$, proved only a few hours ago by Sungjin Kim in [while working on one of our collaboration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3287643/strange-shape-of-the-distribution-of-the-sum-of-the-binomial-coefficients-n-ch). Perhaps this is the fastest case of discovery and reference.

For any $\epsilon > 0$, the value of 
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2n}}{2^n } \bigg\{{n\choose 1^2} + {n\choose 2^2} + {n\choose 3^2} + \cdots + {n\choose r^2}\bigg\}
$$

is more likely to be in the interval is $1 + 2e^{-\pi^2/4} \pm \epsilon$ than any other interval of the same width.

Comment: What does "the most likely value" mean? I think that expression can't ever take on that value, so I'd say it's a *least* likely value. Also, is $r$ related to $n$ in any way? And aren't you the one who was complaining about answers not found in nature???

Comment: @GerryMyerson First part: Upper boundary of the class interval containing the mode. Second part: Yes I was. OP changed the title. But even in the re-title he did not define what he meant by naturally. So I notified him again.

Comment: So far as I can see, OP has never changed the title. What's a "class interval", please?

Comment: First part: OP deleted parts of the question saying he will post in a separate post to differentaite between this post and the new one. Second part: In the graph here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3287643/strange-shape-of-the-distribution-of-the-sum-of-the-binomial-coefficients-n-ch there are two spikes roughly at about $1 \pm 1/6$. The exact location of the spike turns out to be $1 \pm 2e^{-\pi^2/4}$.

Comment: "OP deleted parts of the question...." But OP didn't change the title. So, you are still doing what you have criticized others for doing. And you haven't told me what a "class interval" is. And why $1+2e^{-\pi^2/4}$ in the body, but $1\pm2e^{-\pi^2/4}$ in the comment?

Comment: First part: Yes exactly. Now I can do it because OP clearly did not demarcate between pure math and physical application. Only after that clarification I posted my answers, not before that so I am justified in posting my answers after that point. If he had not done that, I would have still taken natural phenomenon to imply real world or physical applications and so I would have still criticized non-physical answers. Second part: That's because the height of the left spike will be slightly less than the height of the right spike at $a = 1$ in the graph.

Comment: So perhaps you could apologize to those you criticized for doing what you are now doing yourself.

Comment: No, I raised a valid point on the definition of 'natural phenomenon'. Before that, everyone interpreted the question in their own way and answered it without clarifying the OP's which left room or ambiguity. So I don't think I owe an apology for following a better process. I should rather  be appreciated for raising it, getting it clarified and not answering it before it was clarified even though I had more than one answer form pure math.

Comment: You wrote to another user, "Your examples are not applicable unless you tell where they occur in nature." That's not just "raising a valid point on the definition" – that's telling another user (and everyone reading it) that the user's answer is wrong. I reckon that deserves an apology. "not answering it before it was clarified" – but I think the timeline will show OP's clarification, such as it is, came well after you posted your answers.